# Can't change the title in a datepickerdialog

Tags: android

OK.  I have spent hours on this and I can't figure it out.  I have created a separate Class that has the datepickerdialog fragment as follows:

```
public abstract class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements
    DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);


    // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
    return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }
}
```

The code that calls this fragment is:

```
textViewToChange.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

            DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment() {
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
                                    //TODO some stuff here                          
                                    changed = true;
                }
            };

            newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");

            return changed;
        }
    });
```

I have tried everything I could read and I just can't figure out how to set the title.  The title that shows up is today's date.  I want to set the title and also add an icon.  Any help would be great!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13123445/set-datepickerdialog-title-permanently


see this link ... it may helpful to you.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in that direction. I already tried using that one.  The problem is that I don't know what to setTitle to.  In that example they had a DatePickerDialog dpd and therefore just did dpd.setTitle.  I don't have a DatePickerDialog object (that I know of) to reference.

Comment: Actually I took a second look at the link you gave me.  I must have been up too late last night!  I made some changes and it worked.  The changes were:   1. took out the statement "return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);" and replaced it with "DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);"  I was then able to setTitle and setIcon on "dpd". Thanks for giving me that extra push!