# Remove title from DatePickerDialog in Android

Tags: android, android-datepicker

I want to restrict a DatePickerDialog to a minimum value of tomorrow. When I put the code that I show below, the restriction works. However, title text containing the date appears like a header. How can I fix this?

This is my code:

```
 Calendar tempDate = Calendar.getInstance();
 tempDate.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
 toDatePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(tempDate.getTimeInMillis());
```

and the image:

[image: a DatePickerDialog showing a title jue, 29 de dec. de 2016]

Comment: Is it a matter of [setting the title](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13123445/set-datepickerdialog-title-permanently)?

Comment: No, I do not want it to appear

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can either manually set the title to an empty string, or you can request the dialog to have no title.

Former approach:

```
toDatePickerDialog.setTitle("");
```

Latter approach:

```
toDatePickerDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Make sure to do either of these before you call `toDatePickerDialog.show()`

Answer (score 0):

you could fix that easily through the theme with `windowNoTitle` set to true.